# Reorder correctly a sequence of events

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, hungarian-algorithm

I have a problem reordering correctly a sequence of events that are sent by different devices: They are sequential and sometimes it can happen that all of them except for the first one can be bypassed completely or partially.
For example let's suppose to have 3 devices **D1 D2** and **D3**, one has to pass through all of them in this sequence D1 -> D2 -> D3.

The first device **D1** can give me one timestamp every time one person cross it.

The second device **D2** can give me one or more timestamp every time a person is in it's area.

The third device **D3** can give me one timestamp every time one person cross it.
(Sometimes it can happen that **D3** is sent before some timestamp of **D2**).
[image: Preview of the devices]
Now if only one person cross all the devices i can see something like this:

D1: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:24.000

D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:25.700

D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:26.800

D3: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:27.010

In this case i could easily get the correct transition. Let's suppose now we have two person where the second one starts  crossing the devices when the first one is in the middle:

Person 1 - D1: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:24.000

Person 1 - D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:25.700

Person 2 - D1: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:25.900

Person 2 - D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:26.500

Person 1 - D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:26.800

Person 1 - D3: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:27.000

Person 2 - D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:27.400

Person 2 - D3: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:28.000

Is there a way to generate a complete transition of them separately as shown below?

---

**Person 1**

D1: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:24.000

D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:25.700

D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:26.800

D3: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:27.000

---

**Person 2**

D1: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:25.900

D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:26.500

D2: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:27.400

D3: timestamp 20/01/2020 13:45:28.000

---

( obviously i don't have **Person 1** and **Person 2** in the data and the problem must be generalised to n person and different crossings ).

I have to implement a C++ code where i can solve this problem and generate some vectors filled with **complete** transitions (D1->D2->D3). I thought something about an assignment problem but i don't know if i am right.
Any idea?

Comment: I don't really see the point of D2. D1 and D3 are enough to count. D2 cannot help (even if you don't receive anything from D2 you have no way to know whether D3 was bypassed or D2 is being bypassed again and again).

Comment: _i don't have Person 1 and Person 2 in the data_ How then do you associate the data with the person/entity that sent it?  Or is the data in the packets completely independent of the cause of the crossing?

Comment: @spectras to be more specific D3 could be bypassed as D2 but NOT both. the only data that i have, to reconstruct the events, are the timestamps. So for example if someone bypass  D3, after '60s' i can say that this transition is not complete. I use three vector of obj, one for each devices, where every times an event occur i push_back it in its vector. Then i try to check the timestamps between the obj of the vectors, if the difference in time is the lowest between 2 events from different vectors, then they may belong to the same transition. I hope I have been explanatory.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The only data that i receive are device_type = D1,D2,D3. timestamps = "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS" and message = "some stuff specific for each device" i don't see anything else